# Is it ok to load the data from server every time, when fragment or activity is resumed?

Tags: android

I want to create a Android app which shows the list of users registered to my app and other functionalities.

Users of the application are fetched from server every time, when user open the activity or fragment. But it will show a lag of some seconds to user means user can't interact with the view. Is it ok?

On the other side, i think of storing the users in local database for the first time and load the users from the local database in next time. And If any new user will registered to my App, then i must send push notification to all users, which will store the details of the user in the local database.

I am confused on this. If anyone has better solution to this, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: *Is it ok?* - Can you be more specific by what you mean by "OK"? Is there a specific outcome you're looking to avoid? If you're just asking whether users will be OK with the lag, that would be primarily opinion based.

Comment: Mean to make Network call each time, when user open the activity or fragment.

Comment: That wouldn't be *ok* to me but we might have different definitions of ok...

Comment: so let me know, what would be ok for you?

Comment: saving battery life ,good app responsiveness ,avoiding unnecessary processing, avoiding huge amount of short lived data, keeping your heap small seems okay for me. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I think you already know the right answer. 
Implement a database in your app (SQLite) and use data from there on launch and only then update it (on background thread). Add a Service to your app and download new data in some interval using Job Scheduler (to save some battery life).